# Changing UIViewTableCell style not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsindexpath, uitableview

I generate a UITableView that I have got acting like an accordion for e.g:

closed:

- item 1

open:

- item 1

  - sub item1

I currently have the following code that currently styles both the item 1 and sub items.

The problem is that I cannot update the sub item font/text color of the cell. I can change the background color.

It's really confusing.

Can you offer a solution?

Here is a screenshot of the current state of the table view:

[image: Current table view... you can see that the sub items font/color have not changed]

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *ParentCellIdentifier = @"ParentCell";
    static NSString *ChildCellIdentifier = @"ChildCell";

    BOOL isChild = currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex && indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (isChild) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChildCellIdentifier];
    }
    else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
    }

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
    }


    if (isChild) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - currentExpandedIndex - 1];
    }
    else {
        int topIndex = (currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : indexPath.row;
        cell.textLabel.text = [topItems objectAtIndex:topIndex];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
    }

    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    if(!isChild){
        switch (row) {
            case 0:
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.529 green:0.655 blue:0.733 alpha:1];
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.176 green:0.282 blue:0.341 alpha:1];
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.51 green:0.357 blue:0.42 alpha:1];
                break;
            case 3:
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.808 green:0.561 blue:0.216 alpha:1];
                break;
            case 4:
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.631 green:0.655 blue:0.282 alpha:1];
                break;
            case 5:
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.753 green:0.314 blue:0.235 alpha:1];
                break;
            case 6:
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.431 green:0.176 blue:0.416 alpha:1];
                break;
            case 7:
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.078 green:0.506 blue:0.506 alpha:1];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"LoveYaLikeASisterSolid" size:14.0]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Row %lu",(unsigned long)row);
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BOOL isChild = currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex && indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

    if (isChild) {
        NSLog(@"A child was tapped, do what you will with it");
        return;
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if (currentExpandedIndex == indexPath.row) {
        [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
        currentExpandedIndex = -1;
    }
    else {

        BOOL shouldCollapse = currentExpandedIndex > -1;

        if (shouldCollapse) {
            [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
        }

        currentExpandedIndex = (shouldCollapse && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : indexPath.row;

        [self expandItemAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}

- (void)expandItemAtIndex:(int)index {
    NSLog(@"expading");
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray *currentSubItems = [subItems objectAtIndex:index];
    int insertPos = index + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < [currentSubItems count]; i++) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertPos++ inSection:0]];
    }
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [indexPaths release];
}

- (void)collapseSubItemsAtIndex:(int)index {
    NSLog(@"collapsing");
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = index + 1; i <= index + [[subItems objectAtIndex:index] count]; i++) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [indexPaths release];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The cell is being reused. If you want to create a cell with a different style then don't use deque (reuse).

Comment: @DCGoD can you show me where to adjust that snippet? ta

Comment: Could it be that you should modify the attributes of `cell.detailTextLabel` in addition to the ones of `cell.textLabel`?

Comment: I'm an idiot. I thought I was referencing textLabel but it was the detailTextLabel all along.. thanks for making me realise!

Answer (score 2):

The cell is being reused. You need to create a new cell instance for that style (which you can then reuse). Create separate cells for the different styles and return each.

```
if (isChild) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChildCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ChildCellIdentifier];
    }
}
else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
    }
}
```